# Send a Form to one email on submit but to a different email on a different submission?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, email, contact-form

i'm still kinda new in this and don't know where to begin.
I'm looking to create a php contact form where user_1 who fills out the form and submits it sends to Emai_1 and user_2 who fills out the form sends to Email_2 and so it continues between the two. Or is it not possible?

Comment: Store a lookup `user - email` somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to send mail to two different email ids alternatively, So to achieve that you need to store a variable in database, which will hold the value of last_email_sent_to after every submission. and every time you will use the other value to send email to and updates it to the "last_email_sent_to" variable.

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks I will see what i can do, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="sales_submit" value="Contact sales department" />
<input type="submit" name="hr_submit" value="Contact HR department" />
```

On action page, your PHP script:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['sales_submit'])) {
    //send email to Robert
} elseif(!empty($_POST['hr_submit'])) {
    // send email to Sabrina
} else {
    // How the hell did you reach this code without any submit button?
}
```

If the email destination depends on form values, you can use the same technique. Instead of having two submit buttons, you can just, in your PHP code on Form landing page test values and change behaviour. Submit buttons have exactly same behaviour as other inputs

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['question_is_sales_relative'])) {
// do an action for sales
} else {
// ...
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks man, but im not trying to have two submit buttons, only 1 submit button with different actions basically, say user_1 fills in the form and sends to email@1 then user_2 fills out the form sends to email@2 and user_3 would be sent to email@1 again and so it continues, so that one sales email does not get smashed with queries and they will never get the same form submission. Thanks for the reply tho